# ASUS BT400 Bluetooth adapter

Tags: 13.10, bluetooth, asus

All, my new Asus BT400 bluetooth adapter arrived. I suppose I should have checked HCL for this, but I thought I would give it a bash. I am unable to see the BlueTooth Adapter in BlueTooth Manager. Any advice on how I might get Bluetooth working (Ubuntu 13.10) ?

Comment: This works, but I have to do it after every boot. I added it to rc.local and it works fine to enable the bluetooth adapter on startup and connect to a bluetooth mouse.

Answer (score 8):

Found this solution on Launchpad which works:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/906832

ASUS USB-BT400 USB Adapter w/ Bluetooth 4.0 - Ubuntu Linux 13.04 - Fix

```
sudo su -
modprobe -v btusb
echo "0b05 17cb" >> /sys/bus/usb/drivers/btusb/new_id
```

Comment: Would you accept you own answer that works for you.

Comment: No more need to add the vid:pid manually. Since kernel version 3.11.0-15 with the kernel module “btusb” the stick is recognized and activated automatically when plugged in. No need to even touch the terminal. Tested on vanilla debian with non-free repos.