# How to set up bluetooth in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: wireless, 18.04, bluetooth, headphones, firmware

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.I have a headset and I'm trying to connect it to my laptop(hp),when I try switching bluetooth to "On" it displays:"No bluetooth found,plugin a dongle to use bluetooth",I tried to install Blue Managerand blueZ but it displays me :No adapters !,Any one knows the steps of bluetooth configuration ?

1-[image: No Bluetooth found]
[image: Blueman is disable]

I've tried `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net;lsusb;dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm` commands and the results are :

```
:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
    Kernel modules: rtl8188ee
08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [103c:1970]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3a6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


:~$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm
>
```

**Edit 1:**
 After some googling ,I found that I need to buy a [Bluetooth adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/Adaptateur-Bluetooth-Dongle-adapter-Ordinateur/dp/B0191LG58Y) to connect my PC to headphone,I bought one (Bluetooth Dongle (Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd)) and it plugged to my pc and my bluetooth is "On" but my laptop can not detect my device.
[image]
After I plugged the bluetooth adpater and run  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` the result is :

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 19d2:1405 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3a6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

When I run hcitool ,it does not detect the adapter (Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode),and the result is :

```
 hcitool dev
Devices:
```

Comment: Check this out https://askubuntu.com/questions/490346/bluetooth-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts. It could be of help!

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31 ,I edited my questions by including the results of commands.

Comment: You apparently don't have a bluetooth adapter in you computer.

Comment: @SorenA ,I bought one but it still the same problem.

Comment: Was it plugged into the computer when you ran the commands?

Comment: @Jeremy31,of course it plugged into my laptop.

Comment: Those devices either work in Linux or they don't

Comment: I have `Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)` as my adapter and my headphone is [JBL](https://www.jbl.com/wireless-headphones/).My headphone work correctly with phone ,but my laptop can not detect any device(headphone,phone,...).

Comment: @Jeremy31,My problem is similaire to [/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18-04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working),but I did not find a firmeware for my adapter

Comment: Cambridge Silicon Radio bluetooth devices don't need firmware

Comment: I forgot to tell you that my adapter is :  ES-388 Bluetooth USB dongle

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: your last screen shows bluetooth turned off & on in orange. Try toggling that switch..

Comment: Hi @Menai Ala Eddine, try running `dmesg` on terminal and see if you find a line where it says "Bluetooth: file_name.hcd on path /lib/... failed to load error -2". If you do, take note of the file name and try searching for it through a search engine. That is a firmware file that needs to be installed for your dongle otherwise. Maybe @Jeremy31 is right about your dongle not been in need of a firmware but dissecting the problem is always helpful and maybe there is a firmware for it.

Answer (score 6):

I've struggled for years with bluetooth. The bluetooth stack is very complex and has issues but it gets better year by year.

Here's what I have done and it works great

- get yourself a Plugable usb bluetooth adapter (Amazon)
- hot plug it, no need to reboot
- find and install blueman from the repos (bluez never has worked well for me)
- power up your headphones, ready to pair
- open blueman, select devices, find your headphones in the list
- select setup, choose how you want to connect and click next
- after a couple seconds, it should pair
- open sound, scroll to find and select your headphones from the list

Note: You'll have to pair again and select in sound after every boot.

Comment: The blueman can not find the devices !!

Comment: Then your issues are definately deeper than a simple bluetooth manager problem. Prepare to dig deeper into the system but I'm out, bluetooth stack is too complex for me

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine: In my case I had to to restart both, the device and the scan, multiple times. This worked with a china bluetooth receiver with a cheap USB dongle on an old PC. I didn't manage to get them to work for years now!

Comment: This is not a good solution, first you cannot buy any Bluetooth dongle on Amazon for Ubuntu, it won't work, and second, your solution works only if there are minor problems, if the adapter, like in this question, is not set or recognized, I doubt it works in much cases.

Answer (score 1):

What is headset ?

For to speak with microphone ? Or for to listen to music ? (I am deaf Ubuntu Linuxer.)

;-)

In Ubuntu often new hardware is recognized, when hardware is at least 4 months to 6 months old (better 1 year old). Concerning music - it can be that there are additional drivers in packages rhythmbox and in amarok and after installation then hardware is recognized - like it was before with some speakers. You might try to install packages with additionally drivers:

> sudo apt-get install rhythmbox amarok

And here is a different solution for additionally drivers - specially for Bluetooth and else firmware:

[Additional Drivers for Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966219/additional-drivers-for-ubuntu-17-10)

You might configure this.

After this all perform re-boot.

Comment: "often new hardare is recognized, when hardware is at least 4 months to 6 months old", err... no. Not so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that a Soundbot dongle works. It reqired a reboot after insertion and was slow to pick up my headphones, but it did finally.

Answer (score 1):

## RTL8188EE doesn't have bluetooth

I guess the best answer comes from [Linux Mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=271856):

> ### Re: HP Laptop's bluetooth not working
>
> Post by JeremyB » Fri Jun 29, 2018 5:31 am You do not have a bluetooth
> chipset connected, the Rtl8188ee wifi card doesn't have bluetooth

---

Additional [reference](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/Bluetooth/td-p/6789050):

> The parts list for your notebook indicates that it comes with a
> Realtek RTL8188EE 802.11bg/n 1x1 WiFi adapter.
>
> That is a single band, **non bluetooth wifi adapter**.

---

Here is a review of four [Bluetooth USB adapters compatible with Linux](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-usb-bluetooth-adapters/)  for as low as 8 bucks:

[image: Bluetooth USB Adapter.png]

Comment: It means that my adapter does not compatible with my laptop !

Comment: The link says that RTL Chipset doesn't have Bluetooth built-in. But I will Google more links when I get home.

Comment: @MenaiAlaEddine I've put in another link confirming your adapter does **not** have bluetooth capability.

Comment: I purchase[this adapter](https://www.amazon.fr/Adaptateur-Bluetooth-Dongle-adapter-Ordinateur/dp/B0191LG58Y) but it still the same problem.

Comment: For example to get the adapter pictured in my answer to work you would follow these instructions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/406841/asus-bt400-bluetooth-adapter

Comment: It's important that they say "Linux compatible" on the adapter page, before buying. In your Amazon page, but the link you posted above my comment seems to prove it's compatible. People should be very careful about the compatibility, as it brings a lot of problems (from my own experience).

Comment: @Quidam I replaced the single reference with a review of four Linux compatible Bluetooth USB adapters for more choice.

Comment: Thank you! I have made the foolish thing to buy a noname stick thinking I would be able to make it work. Poor me.

Answer (score 0):

I did:

```
sudo modprobe btusb   ( # add the btusb module to the kernel )
sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service
```

And it works!

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: enabled)
Active: active (running) since Fri 2020-11-06 21:38:45 CET; 6s ago
 Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 2434 (bluetoothd)
Status: "Running"
 Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
       └─2434 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

I found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44079184/5446749

Answer (score -1):

I've searched a lot because I got the same problem, Finally I found a code in ubuntu forums that instantly worked:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

> Reboot
>   If you notice weak signal try:

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=1`

> and see if it is better, if not do

`sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sleep 5 && sudo modprobe rtl8723de ant_sel=2`

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Before executing commands it's better to understand it! This is the repo link https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new